# Dynamic objects in delphi

Tags: delphi, dynamic

I know dynamic objects are objects created during run time. I have to make use of dynamic objects for a project, but not quite sure what to do. I'm not too sure what dynamic objects actually are except for the definition and for example once a button is clicked a panel is created, but this isn't exactly what is wanted from me. It is supposed to be more complex and meaningful.

What are other examples of dynamic objects and when or why would you use it?

Comment: It sounds like you mean "components" and "controls" instead of "objects".

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. Let's go back to the beginning. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any instance of a class created at runtime in your code, and freed when you no longer need them. This happens all the time for classes that aren't visual components and can't just be dropped on a form.

Basic examples are things like `TStringList` for working with strings or text files, `TStream` descendants like `TFileStream` or `TResourceStream`, threads using `TThread`, generic lists such as `TList<T>`, and many other classes.

For instance, to work with a text file, an example of a dynamically created `TStringList` could be as follows:

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile('C:\Temp\MyFile.txt');
    SL[0] := 'I changed this line.';
    SL.SaveToFile('C:\Temp\MyFile.txt');
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `TArray<T>` is not an object, it is actually a dynamic `array of T`. Did you mean `TList<T>` instead?

Comment: @Rudy: Yep, you're right. Fixing.

Comment: @Rudy: :-) Happened to be on-site when the comment notification appeared.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a class project, and you don't seem to understand some of the terminology involved.

Just to generalize on this a little bit, in Delphi, instances of ANY class you define need to be created dynamically. This contrasts with records, which can be declared statically as variables as well as allocated dynamically.

In both cases (classes and records), when you create an instance dynamically, the memory for them is allocated from the heap, rather than the stack (where local vars are created). But the syntax is different in each case.

In Delphi, this contrasts sharply with C++, because C++ classes are basically structs (like Delphi records) with some embellishments, meaning that you can declare instances of classes in C++ as member variables where their memory is allocated on the stack in the same way you can declare instances of structs, as well as records in Pascal.

But this doesn't work in Delphi, even though the syntax looks the same. That's because in Delphi, the variables referring to classes are really pointers, like in C++, but they're automatically dereferenced, so they look syntactically as if they're just instances rather than a pointer-to-an-instance.

In Delphi, if you're working with a class, you MUST create it dynamically (by calling TMyObj.Create(...)). Thus, every class has a constructor associated with it; if you don't define one, the default TObject.Create constructor is called. (This is again different than in C++ where a default constructor will be created for you by the compiler for any class that needs one and it's not defined.)

I'll repeat this again so you're clear about it. Anything defined like THIS in Delphi:

```
type
  Twhatever = class
```

is equivalent to this:

```
type
  Twhatever = class( TObject )
```

and absolutely MUST be created dynamically in your code like this:

```
var
  xyz : Twhatever; // xyz is really a pointer here! It's NOT an "instance"
begin
  xyz := Twhatever.Create(); // you need to create an instance using the Create() method
  try
    // do some stuff
  finally
    xyz.Free;
  end;
```

You cannot NOT use xyz without first creating an instance of it via it's .Create method.